# strange issue, keyboard inputs locked by emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs, keyboard

I have a crazy problem on CentOS.

I was doing some editing in emacs when I accidentally hit some keys.  Next thing I know, none of my regular keystrokes work.

I wasn't able to close emacs no matter what I tried (mouse on X doesn't work either).

I logged in from another PC and killed the emacs process.

However, this still doesn't fix the problem.  Now, when I click my desktop shortcut, I can open another konsole, however, I can't type anything into that console!

When I click on the X to close it, I get this black hand, not the regular arrow.

Further, hitting enter doesn't do anything, and any keystrokes I type don't show up in the terminal.

However, if I type s, the Search heading on the terminal window drops down.

Does anybody know how to get out of this weird mode so I can use my PC again?

EDIT:  More information.  I think my linux is stuck in something similar to Windows ALT mode.  For instance, in Windows, when you hit ALT, followed by F, the File menu will drop down.  On my PC, when I hit F, the File menu immediately comes down on the active terminal.  However, I cannot for the life of me get out of this mode.  Been stuck for over an hour now!!

Answer (score 2):

Hitting the ALT key may have solved the problem.  I'm not sure if that was what ended up fixing it, but after I hit the ALT key a bunch of times, I got the VNC display to work properly again.

Comment: Just a note that your original question didn't contain any information about VNC; that might have been useful to know...